# How to correctly run Cuda toolkit in Ubuntu in the WSL (eventually to be used for YOLO)?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mingw-w64, yolo

I followed the tutorial here from the Medium: https://medium.com/@GuruAtWork/setup-fastai-ubuntu-on-windows-10-44ca50b13a9

I was following it well until a MinGW was used for command lines. I am not sure how they went about doing this as the only way I could get `nvcc` to work is with `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. However, this does not seem to complete the same thing as their tool kit is installed as if the exe was just run with Windows. However, that, of course, doesn't work with the Ubuntu. Let me know what you think, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's just not possible right now to do so from WSL. The link from Medium only sets it up for the Git bash prompt, which is not the same as WSL.

Comment: Looks like WSL 2 is supposed to allow for GPU passthrough? I haven't tried it yet myself.